# Given that two cards are honor cards in spades, probability exactly one of them is an ace

Tags: probability

"Given that two cards are honor cards (10, J, Q, K, A) in spades what is the probability that exactly one of them is the ace?"

I'm not really understanding this problem. The solutions say the answer is 8/25. But I computed that there are 20 ways(5*4) to pick spades honor cards from the same deck and 1*4+4*1=8 ways to choose exactly one ace. Thus I have 8/20.

Comment: They might be assuming you are drawing cards *with* replacement (but the statement as given seems to suggest the interpretation you went with).

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Using T for 10, it seems to me your sample space is as follows:

```
 TT TJ TQ TK TA
 JT JJ JQ JK JA
 QT QJ QQ QK QA
 KT KJ KQ KK KA
 AT AJ AQ AK AA
```

The outcomes with exactly one ace are the 8 possibilities
along the right side and the bottom, omitting AA.

Your computation for 20 outcomes in the denominator ignores the
possibility of two cards of the same denomination. As shown
there are 25 possible outcomes.